# Mysqli prepared statement - Data not entering DB (but giving success msg)

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, session-variables

I'm not sure how to title this; been wrestling with this for hours it's kind of a weird problem.

I have the following prepared statement:

```
    $query = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO users 
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
                        ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $query->bind_param('issssssisisiiisssssssssissssi', 
                $empty, $fname, $lname, $username, 
                $em, $hash, $date, $empty, 
                $empty, $empty, $profile_pic, $zero, 
                $zero, $zero, $no, $comma, 
                $empty, $empty, $empty, $empty, 
                $empty, $show, $empty, $empty, 
                $empty, $banner_pic, $banner_pic_two, $token, $two);
    $query->execute();
    $query->close();

    if ($query) {
        array_push($error_array, "<span>Check Your Email to Activate Your Account!</span><br>");
```

There is allot of checks and balances before I get to this point but I'll try and focus this if I can.  When I fill out the register form, I get the message `Check Your Email to Activate Your Account!` So I do this and activate and that checks out too.  When I go to login, it's not in the dB - so of course I get an error msg.  I can also see in phpmyAdmin that it's not there.  So I was thinking it's somewhere in here `$query->bind_param`.  Went through this and how it corresponds to dB and it look good.

BUT (& this is weird), when I enter a First Name and Last Name of someone who is already in the dB, the registration works.  I can't use the same email, (I'll get an error message) but I also can't use a new name with the new email. The names have to be of someone ALREADY in the dB.  This is how `$fname` and `$lname` are input.

```
<div class="account-row">
    <label for="firstname">FIRST NAME</label>
    <input type="text" class="account-input" name="reg_fname" id="firstname" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['reg_fname'])){
    echo $_SESSION['reg_fname'];
    }
    ?>">
</div>
<div class="account-row">
    <label for="lastname">LAST NAME</label>
    <input type="text" class="account-input" name="reg_lname" id="lastname" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['reg_lname'])){
    echo $_SESSION['reg_lname'];
    }
    ?>">
</div>
```

This is how they are handled once the form is submitted:

```
//Declaring varibales to prevent errors
$fname = ""; //First Name
$lname = ""; //Last Name
$email = ""; //email
$em2 = ""; //email 2
$password = ""; //password
$password2 = ""; //password 2
$date = ""; //Sign up date
$banner_pic = "assets/images/banner_pics/default/default.gif";
$banner_pic_two = "assets/images/banner_pics/default/default2.gif";
$error_array = array(); //Holds error messages

if(isset($_POST['register_button'])){

//Registration form values

// First name
$fname = strip_tags($_POST['reg_fname']); //Remove html tags
$fname = str_replace(' ', '', $fname); //Removes spaces
$fname = ucfirst(strtolower($fname)); //Uppercase first letter
$_SESSION['reg_fname'] = $fname; //Stores first name into session variable

// Last name
$lname = strip_tags($_POST['reg_lname']); //Remove html tags
$lname = str_replace(' ', '', $lname); //Removes spaces
$lname = ucfirst(strtolower($lname)); //Uppercase first letter
$_SESSION['reg_lname'] = $lname; //Stores last name into session variable
```

Beyond this I have some code that `concats` the first and last name to create a username and adds integers to the end if it already exists.  This is working, b/c since the names are already in the dB, it just keeps adding 1,2,3 etc. on the end  however many times I sign up with it.  But when I go back to trying to use a new First Name and Last Name, (once again) it won't enter the dB.  Is anyone able to see from what I posted where the issue might be?  I'm working locally, so am wondering if it has something to do with session variables...but I can't see how?

Comment: `$query` is and remains a mysqli statement object. It's not going to turn into a falsey value if the query failed. So yes, `if ($query)` will always be true.

Comment: why would the query succeed only when a name of someone in the dB is input?  My code doesn't care what name is used, I have a function to ensure a username is not duplicated.  Other than that I do nothing with the names.  How can I evaluate the query differently in the `if` statement to see what might be going on?

Comment: ‍♂️ Start with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments.